# Spring boot security authentication in test class

Tags: java, spring, security, testing, endpoint

I want to make test class for my endpoints. It wasnt problem with GET methods but POST is secure by spring security. My error massage:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /books
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 403
    Error message = Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.
          Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY]}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = [[Cookie@45e1aa48 name = 'XSRF-TOKEN', value = '333edde7-e271-41df-a169-03336cd05fc4', comment = [null], domain = [null], maxAge = -1, path = '/', secure = false, version = 0, httpOnly = false]]

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :403
 <Click to see difference>
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(BookEndpoint.class)
@Import(SecurityConfig.class)
public class BookEndpointTest {

    BookDto bookNumberOne;
    BookDto bookNumberTwo;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private BookFacade bookFacade;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        bookNumberOne = BookDto.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .title("Testowa1")
                .author("Anonim1")
                .isbn("1234567890")
                .build();

        bookNumberTwo = BookDto.builder()
                .id(2L)
                .title("Testowa2")
                .author("Anonim2")
                .isbn("1234567890")
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void add() throws Exception {
        given(bookFacade.add(bookNumberOne)).willReturn(bookNumberOne);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/books"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Testowa1")));
    }

}
```

Security class:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).authenticated().and()
                .formLogin().and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

So first I want to test only POST methods with spring security. Ofcourse later I want to figure how to test it with my User Roles in Database :) But small steps... I dont know how to set authorize session. App is on spring boot 1.5.4.

Any advice or example on git will be usefull!
My project is also on my github: https://github.com/kuzyn007/ModuleSpring

Comment: Please anyone give me some advice. Im trying to test POST method with my spring security for many many hours... I cant find any solution for spring boot on google :/

Comment: you need to send csrf cookie in your post request. Check the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#test-mockmvc-smmrpp)